# I'm getting the Travis CI Build Error "Module not found" and I'm not sure why

Tags: python, travis-ci

I'm getting "Module not found" errors for my Travis CI build. I'm not sure exactly why but here's a look at my initial PyTest file:

```
import requests

url_ddg = "https://api.duckduckgo.com"


def test_ddg0():
    resp = requests.get(url_ddg + "/?q=DuckDuckGo&format=json")
    rsp_data = resp.json()
    assert "DuckDuckGo" in rsp_data["Heading"]
```

My travis.yml file contains this following code:

```
language: python
python:
 - "3.8.2"
 - "nightly"
install:
 - "pip install pytest"
 - "pip install -r requirements.txt"
script: python -m pytest Test.py
```

Here's a little look at the error on Travis build log:

```
==================================== ERRORS ====================================
___________________________ ERROR collecting Test.py ___________________________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/travis/build/mjfields-java/PresidentsAPI/Test.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
Test.py:1: in <module>
    import requests
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 1 error in 0.07 seconds ============================
The command "python -m pytest Test.py" exited with 2.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

My requirements.txt file contains this:

```
pytest==4.6
```

Comment: What are the contents of your requirements.txt? Please add it to your question.

Comment: Please do not post a picture of text.  Cut and paste it in the question.  This is to ensure your question is complete, if ever the image link is gone.

Comment: Do not use Travis. They do not have a free model. I tried using it for a dew months and my credits ran out, now they are asking for a subscription. No thanks.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Same - I thought it was free, then I ran out of credits and had to select the free trial. I ended up switching to GH Actions.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up guys. I'll be sure to change from Travis after I'm done with this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `requests` module part of your requirements.txt file? If not, that's the problem. `requests` is sometimes installed by default, but usually not in Linux distributions like what Travis usually runs on.

requirements.txt can look like:

```
pytest==4.6
requests~=2.6.0
```

Comment: Actually now that you mentioned it, it doesn't. I'll edit my question to display my requirements.txt file. "pytest==4.6" is the only thing on the text file. Should I just add "import request" on the text file, or is there a certain way to put it?

Comment: Just add it as a dependency, just like pytest. Requests is installed via pip.

Comment: I've only just recently learned about travis CI, so I'm not entirely good at this yet but would that look like this: pip -install request

Comment: Not in requirements.txt. You could add that as a step in the travis build commands, but easier is just adding `requests~=2.26.0` to the requirements.txt

Comment: By the way: the `pip install pytest` is redundant if you've already got it in your `requirements.txt`

Comment: Alright thanks this works. I'll be editing my comment with that request dependency. I'll be sure to not be so redundant the next time. Thanks for your help.